# Apache Storm InvalidTopologyException

Tags: java, apache-storm, bigdata

I am facing an error during the runtime in the MainTopology class, It shows an error in line no. 24 which i have not been able to understand.
Here is the main class:
      package streamPostsCount;

```
  import backtype.storm.Config;
  import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
  import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
  import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;

  public class MainTopology {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      //Create config instance for cluster configuration
      Config config = new Config();
      config.setDebug(true);

      TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
      builder.setSpout("post-reader-spout", new StreamReaderSpout());

      builder.setBolt("split-post-bolt", new PostSplitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("post-reader-spout");

      builder.setBolt("update-posts-bolt", new PostsUpdateBolt())
    .fieldsGrouping("split-post-bolt", new Fields("posts-by-user"));

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("PostsCount", config, builder.createTopology());
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      //Stop the topology
      cluster.shutdown();
    }

 }
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
  3049 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
  3066 [main] INFO  b.s.d.supervisor - Starting supervisor with id 1a6399fb-360b-4f8f-bd4d-b09711fbcb24 at host mdh160
  3074 [main] INFO  b.s.d.nimbus - [req 1] Access from:  principal: op:submitTopology
  3099 [main] WARN  b.s.d.nimbus - Topology submission exception. (topology name='PostsCount') #<InvalidTopologyException InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [update-posts-bolt] subscribes from stream: [default] of component [split-post-bolt] with non-existent fields: #{"posts-by-user"})>
  3099 [main] ERROR o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
  backtype.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException
at backtype.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:169) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.daemon.common$system_topology_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:299) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__6583$exec_fn__1236__auto__$reify__6598.submitTopologyWithOpts(nimbus.clj:1091) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__6583$exec_fn__1236__auto__$reify__6598.submitTopology(nimbus.clj:1119) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
at backtype.storm.testing$submit_local_topology.invoke(testing.clj:276) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:43) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.submitTopology(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at streamPostsCount.MainTopology.main(MainTopology.java:24) ~[StreamLayer/:?]
```

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: Do not post a screenshot. Copy/paste the COMPLETE stack trace, including all "caused by" sections as text and format as code (indent 4 spaces).

Comment: Yes, did as you suggested. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your emitting bolt (split-post-bolt) needs to also implement declareOutputFields():

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("posts-by-user","field2","field3"));  // list the fields you'll emit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you emit from bolt, you need to override method 
`public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer);` 
and mention what fields you are emitting. Storm is clearly saying that there is no field declared as `posts-by-user` to be emitted from the bolt `split-post-bolt`

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("posts-by-user"));
}
```